# Conditionally Formatting Across Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am organizing an event and would like to do the following:

I have a General sheet with all the invitees names, addresses, etc. I also mark here if they replied and how many people will be attending. I have a separate sheet with the seating, and I was wondering if there is any way to format the **Seating** sheet *based on* the info in the **General** sheet? So that if the "# Attending" column has a value greater than 0, then that particular invitee's row would be automatically entered in to the Seating sheet.

Any ideas??

Comment: Would you want the rows on the **Seating** sheet to correspond the the rows on the **General** sheet? Meaning that if the first and third invitee responded, the second row of the **Seating** sheet would be blank.

Comment: Hm I guess it could go either way - it would be better if the 2nd row wasn't blank, but honestly either way would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine conditional formatting based on a formula. Just choose Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula. In that formula bar you can enter whichever formula you'd like. One that could be particularly useful here would be VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH.

Let's say you'd want to format the value in cell A1 of your seating based on the attendee names in column A of the General sheet, with their presence in column B. You could then use the following as a formatting rule:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,General!$A:$B,2,FALSE) > 0
```

Or, with index/match (faster and cleaner),

```
=INDEX(General!$B:$B,MATCH(A1,General!$A:$A,0)) > 0
```

If you have the room for it, you could put these formulas in your worksheet as well. That way you can make counts of how many people are at a table instead of having to count them manually based on formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! The formulas look great, but I must be doing something wrong because they weren't work for me. Would you be able to help me figure it out? Either when I put the formula in I get "0"s across the board, or simply blanks, or Excel tells me there is a reference error. Any ideas for what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you include, in your original question, an example layout of the General and Seating sheets? With row and column headers. That way I can point out why they're not working.

Comment: I'd love to! I went through and screenshotted every step along the way for you, but then discovered that this site doesn't let you enter pictures without a certain amount of points! This is my first time here and my first question, so I don't have anything. :/

Answer (score 0):

If the rows on the General sheet correspond to the rows on the Seating sheet like so:

[image: General Sheet]

[image: Seating Sheet]

Then all you need to do is:

1.Paste `=IF(General!$C2>0,General!A2,"")` into cell A2 of the Seating sheet.

2. With that cell still selected drag the fill handle to cell C2.
3. With all three cells selected drag down as far as needed to correspond to all used rows of the General sheet.

If you want to get rid of the blank rows, say for a final print out:

1. Select cells A2 through C2.
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+ down arrow.
3. Select the Data tab.
4. In the Sort and Filter pane, select the Z to A sort. (This will put all the blanks at the bottom, and of course can be undone with the undo button)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked! I have a question though; For all cells that were blank on the General sheet, the Seating sheet entered a "0" in the cell. Is there a way to get rid of that and have the cell stay blank?

Comment: Try `=IF(OR(General!$C2=0,General!A2=0),"",General!A2)` instead, and please let me know if it works the way you want.